# How to track events on mediaelement.js using their plugin and universal Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, mediaelement.js, event-tracking

I am trying to implement Google Analytics event tracking on the mediaelement.js audio player. I have succesfully managed to track clicks on links on the page, but I would love to track how many people actually listen to the audio (without offering a download link only and no audio player).

I believe I have done everything right, but apparantly I have not, because it's not working. No events show up in the GA report. I cannot find much by googling. I found a similar question on this site ([How to track events on mediaelement.js with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967620/how-to-track-events-on-mediaelement-js-with-google-analytics)), but it didn't help me.

Can anyone see where the mistakes are? Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Here is the relevant html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="XrefThemes/Theme1/src/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="XrefThemes/Theme1/src/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="XrefThemes/Theme1/src/mep-feature-googleanalytics.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="XrefThemes/Theme1/src/mediaelementplayer.css" />
<title>
Doknr 1383519
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-37025154-3', 'auto', {'name': 'mv', 'allowLinker': true});
  ga('mv.require', 'linker');
  ga('mv.linker:autoLink', ['musikverket.se', 'musikverk.se', 'statensmusikverk.se', 'visarkiv.se', 'muslib.se', 'elektronmusikstudion.se', 'smus.se', 'dramawebben.se'] );
  ga('mv.require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('mv.send', 'pageview');

</script>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Anmärkningar</td>
        <td>
          <div><audio controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg" style="width: 500px" src="http://xref.musikverk.se/visarkivetserver/getfile.aspx?file=audio/SVABA0001-0002.mp3"></audio><br><audio controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg" style="width: 500px" src="http://xref.musikverk.se/visarkivetserver/getfile.aspx?file=audio/SVABA0003-0004.mp3"></audio></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<script>$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the js code (that I found here: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/9d4ceefc75b9936cd32a1c17be761809bbbc0c16/src/js/mep-feature-universalgoogleanalytics.js)
(Thanks nyuen for pointing out that I had missed the mv before send! It is now corrected.)

```
/*
* analytics.js Google Analytics Plugin
* Requires JQuery
*/

(function($) {

$.extend(mejs.MepDefaults, {
    googleAnalyticsTitle: 'Test',
    googleAnalyticsCategory: 'Mediafiles',
    googleAnalyticsEventPlay: 'Play',
    googleAnalyticsEventPause: 'Pause',
    googleAnalyticsEventEnded: 'Ended',
    googleAnalyticsEventTime: 'Time'
});


$.extend(MediaElementPlayer.prototype, {
    builduniversalgoogleanalytics: function(player, controls, layers, media) {

        media.addEventListener('play', function() {
            if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                ga('mv.send', 'event',
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsCategory,
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsEventPlay,
                    (player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle === '') ? player.media.currentSrc : player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle
                );
            }
        }, false);

        media.addEventListener('pause', function() {
            if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                ga('mv.send', 'event',
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsCategory,
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsEventPause,
                    (player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle === '') ? player.media.currentSrc : player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle
                );
            }
        }, false);

        media.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                ga('mv.send', 'event',
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsCategory,
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsEventEnded,
                    (player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle === '') ? player.media.currentSrc : player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle
                );
            }
        }, false);

        /*
        media.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
            if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
                ga('mv.send', 'event',
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsCategory,
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsEventEnded,
                    player.options.googleAnalyticsTime,
                    (player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle === '') ? player.media.currentSrc : player.options.googleAnalyticsTitle,
                    player.currentTime
                );
            }
        }, true);
        */
    }
});

})(mejs.$);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created your tracking object, you gave it the name 'mv', so when you send your events, you'll have to use there same name

```
ga('mv.send', 'event', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I should have thought of that. Unfortunately it didn't help, so there must be something else as well.

Comment: Try using a tool like Tag Assistant to see if hits are going through. Keep in mind that events (and every other hit type) don't show up in your reports until after the data has been processed, which could take up to 24 hours).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not familiar with Tag Assistant and might not have time to look into it (if I cannot figure this out we will let our web firm have a go, but I really hope that we don't have to do that). I'm always looking at the real time report and it works perfectly fine with all my other events.

Comment: Sorry, not Tag Assistant, but rather GA Debugger (it's a free Chrome plugin and you can install and shows you debug messages in the Dev Console). With that you can see if the event hit is going through or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's a cool plugin that I didn't know about. Unfortunately nothing at all happens in the console when I press play, so there are no hints as to why the script is not working.

Comment: Hi Lena,
Did you ever get it working?   (as I have the same problem)